# How to reload same fragment from within itself in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I want to recall my Fragment which sends request to server for some data.
The reason is at first request server returns 8 values, when scroll bar hits the bottom(have done it) the fragment must send another request to load another 8 values. is it possible to do it within the same fragment and with the same objects to store another values.?

**thanks..**

Comment: You must be using ListView with Lazy load, let us also know the type of data you are loading?

Answer (score 0):

A very lazy way of simply getting your tabs to refresh is to add "mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1); mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3); " into the callback . it gets the job done.